# Concentrate text not function properly (Yii2 framework)

Tags: php, yii2

I want to concentrate some text from another table and put it in a new field.

```php
$model1 = new CourseDetails();

$model1->course_shortform= CourseDetails::find()->select('course_shortform')->where(['course_name'=>$model->course_name]);
```

And then using the code below I was able to get the value from another table to fill in the field like so:

```php
$model->intake_no = $model1->course_shortform;
```

Its all going well until i wanted to add some text for the intake no column:

```php
$model->intake_no = $model1->course_shortform . "This is new text" ;
```

The system didn't display errors but it will show the text like this:

[image: ref]

I wonder if got some alternative method to concentrate the text but I can't figure it out. I will glad if someone can help.

Comment: you are missing the `->one()` in the end of your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `CourseDetails` model then you create a query (instance of `ActiveQuery`) for selecting `course_shortform` and assigning that query into `course_shortform` property in that code of yours.

Instead of that you should skipt this line:

```php
$model1 = new CourseDetails();
```

And you should use your query to find one model like this:

```
$model1 = CourseDetails::find()
    ->select('course_shortform')
    ->where(['course_name'=>$model->course_name])
    ->one();
```

Or if you need to create instance for `$model1` by yourself you should use `scalar()` method to get the value returned by select directly.

```php
$model1 = new CourseDetails();

$model1->course_shortform = CourseDetails::find()
    ->select('course_shortform')
    ->where(['course_name'=>$model->course_name])
    ->scalar();
```

Comment: Ok i see. I also found another way by removing the ->course_shortform in the find statement. I guess because i am trying to access the query text into another text field. Thank you for the response anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the fecth function  ..  for a model should be ->one()

```
$model1 = new CourseDetails();

$model1= CourseDetails::find()
    ->select('course_shortform')
    ->where(['course_name'=>$model->course_name])
    ->one();
```

and you should not assign the model to text field var so you don't  $model1->course_shortform  but on $model1

Comment: well i added but didnt work, but now i solved it by removing  the
  ->course_shortform in the find statement.  I guess it because i accidentally  declaring the query text into the text field. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: you can't assign a model  to  a  text field  ..the main question is related to teh fatc you don't fecth  the  ..  the model ...  so adding the one() function you retrive the model and you can discover that you assigning the model ..  to the right var ...  ..  anyway you shoul choose the answer that lead your solution and mark it as accepted .. overall now the answer  contain the right suggestion